# mono android database

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin.android

what's the best database we can use to develop application for mono android? best I mean simple to and maintain.. and with features like full text search. and keeping in mind later I'll need to develop an iphone version of the same application as well. so I'll need to use a database that can be used both for mono android and mono ios..

i'm under the impression that there's at least sqlite for mono android, but do mono android offers other database? if yes, is it better than sqlite? and speaking about sqlite, there's very little help I can find on the net on a monodroid newbie like me to.. so I'm pretty stucked currently. the tutorial I find here http://www.elucidsoft.com/blog/2011/12/31/mono-android-working-with-sqlite/ is very simple, while http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/02/using-a-database-in-monodroid-applications/ are pretty massive for me (the source code at least) because they don't describe in details on that page what do the attached source code do..  so any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of support for any other databases on Android and the Iphone other than sqlite.

The best way to develop for SQLite databases IMO on MonoDroid/Monotouch is using the sqlite-net library. Gregshackles has given an example of how to use this in the link that you gave in the section titled "The ORM Way".

You can view the sqlite-net project [here](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/). To share the database code between MonoDorid and Monotouch you should write the code in a shared project using the techniques outlined [here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/12/shared-libraries-for-windows-phone-7-monodroid-and-beyond/).

Comment: thanks for the info, but I don't think I can find anything like Project Linker in mono droid

Comment: If you are using Monodevelop and you need to link the projects you can link to the files within the project. This is builtin to Monodevelop just like Visual Studio. The Project Linker plugin just makes it easier as it automatically links new files as they are added to the project. All this means is that each time you add a new file to your base project you must link to the file in the MonoDroid project.